# Progress Bar inside TabHost in android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-progressbar

[image: i want to show a progress bar in the tabhost , while the image in the tabhost is loading ,, is this possible , i made this sample image in Paint just to give an idea of the UI in my mind regarding tab host..]
i want to show a progress bar in the tabhost , while the image in the tabhost is loading ,, is this possible , i made this sample image in Paint just to give an idea of the UI in  my mind regarding tab host..

how can i achieve this,, the progress bar should appear inside the tabhost.

Comment: well for sure ,,, any idea you have

Answer (score 0):

Try this.See you need progress bar while loading the tab.For that you can use `AsyncTask` while loading the view so until your complete view is not loaded it will show progress bar if you define it at proper place in your code.

And another thing is you can use `selector` .This my help you.Please read this post http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/ and let me know it it works or not.

Hope this helps you.  :)

Comment: Its differernt thing you are saying. answer is not acceptable , then y to confuse other viewers by accepting it....let me be more clear .. this is the XML file  it contans a TabHost and a Frame Layout , Where should i put the Progress Bar. Seems it is not allowed to put a progress inside a tabhost.. i goggled everywhere , but din able to find.

Comment: Ok I don't said that you have to accept answer.I said try this if you feel this is really helpful then accept it otherwise don't.In this way you are not going to confuse the viewer.